# How to arrange cards to form a grid view in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gridview, jsx

I want to arrange the cards in such a way that it should form a grid view.I've tried several grid view component , but I can't make navigation to each item within data of `npm install react-native-super-grid`.So I thought making grid view with `CardSection` of my own.But I don't know how to arrange it within a row of 2 cards per each row.Following is my code for CardSection

**cardsection**

```
  const CardSection = (props) =>{
    return(
    <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
    {props.children}
    </View>
    );

};
const styles ={
    containerStyle: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth:0,
        marginBottom:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight:10,
        borderColor:'#808080',
        marginTop:50,
        elevation: 10,
        flexDirection:'row',
       flexWrap:'wrap'
    }
};
```

What I've tried now is just listing the cards as follows

**list**

```
  <CardSection>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.newworkRequest()}>
      <Text>New Work Request</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.workerDetails()}>
    <Text>Worker</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.reportViewing()}>
    <Text> Reports</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.compltpage()}>
    <Text> Complaints</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </CardSection>
  <CardSection>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.userpage()}>
    <Text> Users</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </CardSection>
```

How do I make this as a grid view ? Such that 2 cards within a row.Please help.This is what I'm getting now  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtnuv.png .I've tried to give `FlexDirection:row` , but all the cards will come in the same row.So I removed that.Please help me for a solution.

Comment: Try putting 
`flexDirection: row`
`flexWrap: wrap`

Comment: I've changed the `containerStyle` of `CardSection`  but no difference.Updated my code please have a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to apply these styles on the parent of all these Card sections..

```
const styles ={
  mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  containerStyle: {
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth:0,
        marginBottom:10,
        marginLeft:10,
        marginRight:10,
        borderColor:'#808080',
        marginTop:50,
        elevation: 10
    }
}
```

**List**

```
<View style={styles.mainContainer}>
  <CardSection style={styles.containerStyle} />
  ...
</View>
```

Comment: my pleasure @anu